# PasswordRecovery control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, password-recovery

I created my web application and user `PasswordRecovery` Control.
My code in html :

```xml
<asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordRecovery1" runat="server">
     <MailDefinition From="mail@gmail.com" Subject="ResetPassword"
      Priority="High"/>
</asp:PasswordRecovery>
```

And my web.config code is:

```xml
<system.net>
     <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="mail@gmail.com">
           <network
              host="smtp.gmail.com"
              port="25"
              password="xxxxxxx"
              defaultCredentials="true"/>
        </smtp>
     </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

But I get these errors and it doesn't work.

> 1-The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.
>
> 2-A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 173.194.66.109:25

---

my web.config code is

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <roleManager enabled="true" />
        <authentication mode="Forms" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

    <!-- ... -->

    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp from="mail@gmail.com">
                <network host="smtp.gmail.com" password="mypassword"
                 enableSsl="true" port="578" userName="hsadeghi.t@gmail.com" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

and form :

```xml
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Masters/master-store.Master"
  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UserPasswordRecovery.aspx.cs"
  Inherits="Store.Pages.userpasswordrecovery" %>

<!-- ... -->
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper-rim">
            <div class="site-content">
                <div class="recovery-password" dir="rtl">
                    <asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordRecovery1" runat="server"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Chack This Link.

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097333/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from enabling ssl in your configuration, you also need to set the correct **port**, which is *not* 25. It's 587.

```xml
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="someaccount@gmail.com">
   <network
      host="smtp.gmail.com"
      port="587"  
      enableSsl="true"
      userName="someaccount@gmail.com"
      password="somepassword"
      defaultCredentials="false"/>
</smtp>
```

Comment: **WHAT** doesn't work? You have to learn that we will refuse to **guess** what's wrong. Be detailed.

Comment: Did you remember to **change** the **port**?

Comment: The basic steps of problem solving: 1. List what you've tried. 2. List why that didn't work (as in, provide the REASON returned with any error message). 3. Search (google) for those error messages. 4. Search (google) for basic information on your task.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that connection is secure:

```
<network enableSsl="true" ...
```

Comment: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 173.194.78.109:25

Answer (score 0):

There is a very important error in an earlier answer.

The `defaultCredentials` attribute should be `false` not `true`, in order for it to work with Gmail.